# How to use http_referer if form field and php script are at the same page?

Tags: php

Suppose i am using pure **php**, with no javascript/jquery or ajax.

I have many pages in a website, lets say page1, page2, page3 and page4.
all of the first three pages have a link to go to page4, to log in.

In page 4 i have a form field, and above I have a **php** script to catch the user input and put the username in a session and after that i want to redirect to the page where the user came from, but the page is not redirecting. 
Let me put the code.

```
<?php 
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['username'])){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){

$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header('location: '.$referer);

}

}



?>

<form action="page4.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am starting again all page1, page2, page3 with `ob_start()` and session_start();

If I use a specific page into the header function then it is redirecting, no problem
for example header (`location: page2.php`).
I am guessing the reason is maybe as my form field and the php script are at the same page (page4)
So how to **redirect dynamically**? User might come from page 1 or page2 or page 3 and after log in i want them back to the specific page they came from.

Comment: Is there a submit button in page 1,2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

In page1.php, page2.php, page3.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['page'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

in page4.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
// process form
if ($form_proccessed == true) // or whatever
{
    header("Location: {$_SESSION['page']}\r\n");
    exit;
}
```

Using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` you wont have to worry about updating the code if you save the file as a new file with a new name.

Comment: Hi , this helped me solve the redirect problem , however if user visits page 4 at first before visiting any other pages , i want them redirect to a specific page , lets say page1.php. But it is not working here , it is always redirecting me to the page where last time i came from, because the last $_SESSION['page'] never got unset. so to unset this particular session i tried the code below , but showing syntax error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_UNSET ,

Comment: i tried at page4.php, if(unset($_SESSION['page'])){header('location: page1.php'); exit;}else{header('location: '.$_SESSION['page']); unset($_SESSION['page']); exit;}

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with an hidden input field inside the form :

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value="$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]">
```